# How to combine multiple records from a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm out of my depth with this SQL query.

I have two tables A and B with shared data based on a serial number. In table A, there is a unique Serial Nr field, while in B, details relating to a particular serial number are linked vertically over multiple records by a common Group ID. The serial number entry occurs as one of those records in the MyData field. I want to concatenate all records that share the same "Group ID" to a single field in A. For example:

Table A

```
Serial Nr      Name        Part Nr
 2950          Prod1       1234
 2955          Prod2       2345
```

Table B

```
Group ID       MyData       Comments
    1           2950        serial nr
    1           2016-10     build month   
    2           2955        serial nr
    2           2015-11     build month
```

and I want Table AxB

```
Serial Nr      Name        Part Nr    Table B data
 2950          Prod1       1234        serial nr, 2950, build month, 2016-10
 2955          Prod2       2345        serial nr, 2955, build month, 2015-11
```

I don't actually want the shared Group ID, but need it as concatenation key.

I have tried to do this with STUFF, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: The reference to `STUFF()` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  You should tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your "TableB" also has a "SerialNr" field (which you just did not model);

That is to say, your Table B actually looks like this:

```
Serial Nr   Group ID    MyData      Comments
   2950     1           2950        serial nr
   2950     1           2016-10     build month   
   2955     2           2955        serial nr
   2955     2           2015-11     build month
```

If so, the following query will aggregate the "Comments" and "MyData" columns into a single row per SerialNumber:

```
SELECT  serialno ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Comments + ' - ' + MyData [text()]
FROM TableB 
WHERE SerialNo = t.SerialNo
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') AggregatedData
FROM TableB t
GROUP BY serialno
```

You could then join that query to your original TableA to obtain the result set you posted, ie:

```
select * 
from TableA
join (SELECT  serialno ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Comments + ' - ' + MyData [text()]
      FROM TableB 
      WHERE SerialNo = t.SerialNo
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') AggregatedData
    FROM TableB t
    GROUP BY serialno
    ) AggregatedTableB
on TableA.SerialNo = AggregatedTableB.SerialNo
```

---

### UPDATED:

Ok - so based on the fact that your "TableB" doesn't have its own SerialNr row, and instead its buried within the table data..  You need to find a way to extract that row-level data into a column.

Here is a query that can do that:

```
select tableB.GroupId, MyData, Comments, SerialNo 
from tableB
join
    (select MyData as serialNo, groupId
     from tableb
     where Comments ='serial nr') TableBWithSerialNo on tableB.GroupId = TableBWithSerialNo.GroupId
```

Now that you have this query which adds the Serial No as a column, you can use it in place of just using TableB in the above query.  Here's what it would look like:

```
SELECT  SerialNo ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Comments + ' - ' + MyData [text()]
FROM 
(select tableB.GroupId, MyData, Comments, SerialNo 
 from tableB
 join
    (select MyData as serialNo, groupId
     from tableb
     where Comments ='serial nr') TableBWithSerialNo on tableB.GroupId = TableBWithSerialNo.GroupId
) t1

WHERE t1.SerialNo = t2.SerialNo
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') AggregatedData
FROM (select tableB.GroupId, MyData, Comments, SerialNo 
 from tableB
 join
    (select MyData as serialNo, groupId
     from tableb
     where Comments ='serial nr') TableBWithSerialNo on tableB.GroupId = TableBWithSerialNo.GroupId
) t2
GROUP BY SerialNo
```

Granted - this is one *ugly* query - but that's one *ugly* table you are working with ;-)

If anything, I'd recommend making the first query into a view, and then using that view in the second query - that way you aren't repeating so much code, ie;

```
create view TableBView as
select tableB.GroupId, MyData, Comments, SerialNo 
from tableB
join
    (select MyData as serialNo, groupId
     from tableb
     where Comments ='serial nr') TableBWithSerialNo on tableB.GroupId = TableBWithSerialNo.GroupId

go

SELECT  SerialNo ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Comments + ' - ' + MyData [text()]
FROM 
TableBView t1
WHERE t1.SerialNo = t2.SerialNo
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') AggregatedData
FROM TableBView t2
GROUP BY SerialNo
```

Comment: Almost! I don't, in fact, have a Serial Nr field in Table B. In B the serial number is buried in one record of several grouped by Group ID. My original question was vague, sorry, but the example stands. I hope most will agree Table B is a terrible way to structure a table - but that's how it stands.

Comment: Hehe - that *is* a terrible way to structure a table.  Edgar Codd (inventor of relational DB's normal form) is turning over in his grave looking at the table ;-)  - Anyway - I'll see if I can adapt my answer to fit...

Comment: **Brilliant!** It worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Exactly the help I needed.